# readcsv in Julia without end of line marker

Tags: csv, julia

New to Julia, I am trying to do the Euler project problem.
I got to problem 22 where I need to read a csv file.

I do

```
rawNames=readcsv("names.txt")
```

I get

```
1x5162 Array{Any,2}
```

however I know there are 5163 names to be read and the last one is missing.

Is it because there is not EOL at the end of the file?

How should I read the csv file?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This seems to work for me on trunk; what version of julia are you running?  (It's possible something was changed between 0.2.1 and the 0.3 prerelease I'm using.)

Comment: Will try 0.3 tomorrow (I am on 0.2.1 on 32 bits windows) and report back

Comment: Actually tried at home with 0.3 and it is working. So time to upgrade to 0.3.... Thanks for pointing this out. For a while I thought I needed a secret argument.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems no longer present in the current version of Julia. Upgrade to 0.3 or later to avoid the issue.